# In python, how do you search for a tag value pair in a JSON file

Tags: python, json

Im dealing with a large json file that has many boolean values, so I cant just search on the value alone.  How can I extract the entire user information if one value is true?

For example the json file has many lines that could read something like this:

```
[
    12,
    {
        "name": "Big Bird",
        "muting": false,
        "following": true,
        "blocked_by": false,
        "followers_count": 42
    }
]
```

How can I iterate through the file to find all users who could be set to muting as true?

The code I have is
import json

```
with open("tempList") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for key in data:
        if key['muting'] == "false":
            print("YES")
        else:
            print("$*%#!@")
```

Comment: "The code I have is" Okay, so **what happens** when you try this code? **How is that different** from what is supposed to happen? What specifically is your **question about the approach**? [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to [diagnose](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) a concrete problem with this approach? "For example the json file has many lines that could read something like this:" What **actually** is the structure here? In particular, what does the `12` **mean**?

Comment: "How can I extract the entire user information if one value is true?" **What is** "the entire user information" in this example? (Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Question standards have changed a lot since 2011. **Please** read [ask] and [mre].)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears some values for `user` will be integers, we can explicitly check the type of `user` to avoid problems; also, using `.get` to access the dict will avoid `KeyError` if the key is not present. Thus:

```
users_with_muting = []
with open("tempList") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    for user in data:
        if type(user) == dict and user.get("muting") == True:
            users_with_muting.append(user)
```

Answer (score -1):

For the first question

How can I extract the entire user information if one value is true?

```
def get_user_with_true(json_file: str):
    users_with_true = []
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        json_str = f.read()
        json_data = json.loads(json_str)
        for u in json_data:
            if True in u.values():
                users_with_true.append(u)
    return users_with_true
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that by "one value", OP meant "a specific value".